# useState in ReactJS not updating the object inside Context Provider - In multiple Layouts

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the below authentication context provider. I set the some token values upon successful authentication of the user

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import Constants from "../common/Constants";
import Payload from "../classes/Payload";

const AuthenticationContext = createContext({
    loggedUserToken: {},
    session: {}
});

export const useAuthenticationStatus = () => useContext(AuthenticationContext);

const AuthenticationContextProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [loggedUserToken, setLoggedUserToken]     = useState({});
    const [session, setSession]                     = useState({});


    const authenticateUser = async (loginEndpoint, email, userPassword) => {         

        let result                                  = {};
        let statusCode                              = -1;
        let statusText                              = '';
        let message                                 = '';
        let session                                 = '';
        let postData                                = {username: email, password: userPassword};

        await axios.post(loginEndpoint, postData, {headers: headerData})
                .then( data => {

                    statusCode                      = data.data.code;
                    statusText                      = data.data.statusText;
                    session                         = data.data.session;
                    message                         = data.data.message;

                    if (statusCode === 200) {                

                        let challengeName           = message.challengeName;
                        let payloadData             = '';
                        
                        if (session !== null && message.challenge !== null) {

                            let userEmail           = message.userEmail;
                            setSession({'sD': session, 'sE': userEmail });
                            
                            if (challengeName === Constants.COGNITO_CHALLENGE_NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED ) {
                                statusText          = Constants.AUTHENTICATION_SET_NEW_PASSWSORD;
                                payloadData         = challengeName;
                            }

                            result = { 's': true, 'sT': statusText, 'p': payloadData};

                        } else {
                            statusText              = Constants.AUTHENTICATION_LOGIN_SUCCESSFUL;
                            payloadData             = message;

                            let userpayloadData      = new Payload(payloadData);

                            //set use state for user token - ERROR IN HERE
                            //loggedUserToken IS NOT SET HERE
                            setLoggedUserToken(loggedUserToken => userpayloadData);

                            result = { 's': true, 'sT': statusText, 'p': payloadData};

                        }                        

                    }

                }).catch( error => {
                    
                    result = { 's': false, 'sT': Constants.COMMON_ERROR_MESSAGE, 'p': ''};

                });

        return result;  
    }

    

    return (
        <AuthenticationContext.Provider
            value={{loggedUserToken, authenticateUser, session, setPermanentPassword}}>
            {children}
        </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
    )
};

export default AuthenticationContextProvider;
```

And I have used the "loggedUserToken" value in the home view to check if it is available.

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useAuthenticationStatus } from "../../services/AuthenticateContextProvider";

function HomeView() {

    const {loggedUserToken} = useAuthenticationStatus();
    
    //empty object output
    console.log(loggedUserToken);

    useEffect( () => {
        //empty object output
        console.log(loggedUserToken);
    })

    return (

        
        <div className="col-12">
            
            <div className="row mt-2">
                <div className="col-12">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="row mt-5 incident-list-map">

                <div className="col-md-4">

                    <h2>List</h2>
                    
                    <div></div>

                </div>

                <div className="col-md-8">
                    <div id="map" className="map">
                        
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    );
}

export default HomeView;
```

Eventhough you set it in the authentication provider, the "loggedUserToken" is always empty (Even if you console log it right after "setLoggedUserToken" it on the authentication provider). Where "setSession" is set properly, where I read that value in a different view.

I am not sure what is going wrong in here

UPDATE: below is how I use the authentication provider. The "Outlet" replaces the different views in the MainLayout.

```js
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import MainHeader from "../common/MainHeader";
import MainFooter from "../common/MainFooter";
import AuthenticationContextProvider from "../../services/AuthenticateContextProvider";

function MainLayout() {

    return(

        <div className="main-layout">
            <AuthenticationContextProvider>
                <header>
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top header-area">
                        <MainHeader></MainHeader>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                
                <main className="flex-shrink-0 main-area">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="main-content">
                            
                                <Outlet />
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </main>

                <footer className="footer mt-auto py-3 footer-content">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <MainFooter></MainFooter>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </AuthenticationContextProvider>
        </div>

    );

}

export default MainLayout;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. The above error happened because of layouts I used. I use one layout for authentication views (like login, register etc...) and another layout for other views (home, contact us etc...)

And I have encapsulated those with the authentication context provider separately. Like below;

```js
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import MainHeader from "../common/MainHeader";
import MainFooter from "../common/MainFooter";
import AuthenticationContextProvider from "../../services/AuthenticateContextProvider";

function MainLayout() {

    return(

        <div className="main-layout">
            <AuthenticationContextProvider>
                <header>
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top header-area">
                        <MainHeader></MainHeader>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                
                <main className="flex-shrink-0 main-area">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="main-content">
                            
                                <Outlet />
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </main>

                <footer className="footer mt-auto py-3 footer-content">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <MainFooter></MainFooter>
                    </div>
                </footer>
            </AuthenticationContextProvider>
        </div>

    );

}

export default MainLayout;
```

```js
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import MainHeader from "../common/MainHeader";
import MainFooter from "../common/MainFooter";
import AuthenticationContextProvider from "../../services/AuthenticateContextProvider";

function MainLayout() {


    return(

        <div className="main-layout">
            
                <header>
                    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top header-area">
                        <MainHeader></MainHeader>
                    </nav>
                </header>
                
                <main className="flex-shrink-0 main-area">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="main-content">
                            
                                <Outlet />
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </main>

                <footer className="footer mt-auto py-3 footer-content">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <MainFooter></MainFooter>
                    </div>
                </footer>

        </div>

    );

}

export default MainLayout;
```

But when I moved the authentication context provider to the App.js like below it worked. In my understanding what I think was happened was when it moved from authentication layout to the main layout, the authentication context provider was reset (kind of it is a separate context provider for the main layout). But since I moved the context provider to the very top (App.js) it is now common on all layouts.

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthenticationLayout from './components/layouts/AuthenticationLayout';
import LoginView from './components/authentication/LoginView';
import ForgotPasswordView from './components/authentication/ForgotPasswordView';
import MainLayout from './components/layouts/MainLayout';
import HomeView from './components/main/HomeView';
import ConfirmEmailView from './components/authentication/ConfirmEmailView';
import SetNewPassword from './components/authentication/SetNewPassword';
import AuthenticationContextProvider from './services/AuthenticateContextProvider';

function App() {

  return (

    <>
      <AuthenticationContextProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={ <AuthenticationLayout /> }>
            <Route path='/' element={ <LoginView /> }></Route>
            <Route path='/login' element={ <LoginView /> }></Route>
            <Route path='/forgotpassword' element={ <ForgotPasswordView />}></Route>
            <Route path='/confirmemail'element={ <ConfirmEmailView /> }></Route>
            <Route path='/setnewpassword' element={ <SetNewPassword /> }></Route>
          </Route>

          <Route element={ <MainLayout /> }>
            <Route path='/home' element={ <HomeView /> }></Route>
          </Route>

        </Routes>
      </AuthenticationContextProvider>
    </>

  );

}

export default App;
```